# Providing a generic instance in Kotlin & Guice

Tags: guice, kotlin

I have a Guice `Module` that provides a `List<String>` using a `@Provides`-annotated method.

```
class TestModule() : Module {
  override fun configure(binder: Binder) {}
  @Provides fun getStrings(): List<String> = listOf("foo", "bar")
}

class Test {
  @Test fun `provider can not deliver`() {
    val injector = Guice.createInjector(TestModule())
    injector.getInstance(object : Key<List<String>>() {})
  }
}
```

The test, however, fails with:

```
1) No implementation for java.util.List<? extends java.lang.String> was bound.
  while locating java.util.List<? extends java.lang.String>
```

Now, this seems to be the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36625168/bind-list-of-objects-using-guice-kotlin) but I have no idea where to add the `@JvmSuppressWildcards` annotation; adding it to the `getStrings()` method doesn’t change anything, as does adding it to the `object` in the `getInstance()` call. How do I get Guice to do what I want?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After lots of trial and error I arrived at this solution:

```
@Test
fun `provider can not deliver`() {
  val injector = Guice.createInjector(TestModule())
  injector.getInstance(object : Key<List<@JvmSuppressWildcards String>>() {})
}
```

It’s the last place I would have thought that the annotation is actually valid but suddenly the test was green.

Comment: Wow, same—very surprised that is where the annotation belongs